# Vertex degree and graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Suppose I have two simple graphs $G(V,E)$ and $H(V,E)$ with number of vertices $N$. And $\forall i \quad \text{such that}\quad 0<i<N$

No:of elements in $V(G)$ with degree $i $ = No:of elements in $V(H)$ with degree $i$

Where $V(G)$ is the vertex set of $G$.

Given this can we say that $H$ and $G$ are isomorphic?

If they are not isomorphic. Then what is such a relation called?

Comment: If there are $N$ vertices there can only be a maximum degree of $N-1$.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk: Note that since the number of vertices in $G,H$ is the same, it suffices to check that they have equal numbers of vertices with degrees $i=1,\ldots,N-1$ to prove the same degree sequences (equal numbers of isolated vertices is then forced).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two graphs $G$ and $H$ satisfying the condition you describe are said to have the same degree sequence.  But this does not necessarily imply that the two graphs are isomorphic.  It is possible to construct two graphs that have the same degree sequence but which are not isomorphic.

There is no known list of graph properties (be it the degree sequence, any other graph invariant, or even a combined list of such invariants) that provides a sufficient condition for two given graphs to be isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

**Explicit counterexample:**
fix $G = C_6$ and $H = C_3 \sqcup C_3$, respectively, the $6$-cycle and the disjoint sum of two $3$-cycles. Both have $6$ nodes of degree $2$, hence same degree sequences, but they are not isomorphic since $G$ is connected while $H$ is not.

For a far more advanced treatment of the topic, I suggest [Cai, Fürer, Immerman](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Eimmerman/pub/opt.pdf) or the [textbook](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/descriptive-complexity-canonisation-and-definable-graph-structure-theory/BC758F6004BD96F6995D5F1EF1E29BAD) by Grohe.